# how to reduce the time complexity of two nested loop by using Map in java

Tags: java, arrays, list, hashmap, time-complexity

I have two List of employeeData object

```
List<EmployeeDatas> allEmployees
List<EmployeeDatas> currentEmployees

Class EmployeeDatas {
String name;
String lastName;
String joiningDate;
String promotionDate;
}
```

I want to compare the second list data with the first one without using the double nested loop

if the data matched return true otherwise false.

```
for (allEmployee : allEmployees) {
    for ( currentEmployee : currentEmployees ) {
         if(allEmployee.name.equal(currentEmployee.name) &&   
                allEmployee.lastName.equal(currentEmployee.lastName) && 
                allEmployee.joiningDate.equal(currentEmployee.joiningDate) &&
                allEmployee.promotionDate.equal(currentEmployee.promotionDate)) {
                     return true;
                }
    }
}
```

is it possible to use Map and solve it in O(N) time rather O(N^2)

Comment: The goal is to check if the lists have exactly the same employees? If so your existing implementation doesn't do that at all.

Comment: But yes, you can use hash maps or hash sets to do this faster, whichever you intend. Think about how long it will take to load one entire list into into a hash map, then what you can do with each element of the other list using that hash map

Comment: @EdwardPeters Could you please share the Map or set implementation?

Comment: Try it yourself, and if you run into errors I'll help you understand and solve them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HashSet` for that purpose. But for that, you need the `equals/hashCode` contract to be properly implemented.

Here's an example:

```
public class EmployeeData {
    private String name;
    private String lastName;
    private String joiningDate;
    private String promotionDate;
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        
        return o instanceof EmployeeData other
            && Objects.equals(name, other.name)
            && Objects.equals(lastName, other.lastName)
            && Objects.equals(joiningDate, other.joiningDate)
            && Objects.equals(promotionDate, other.promotionDate);
    }
    
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name, lastName, joiningDate, promotionDate);
    }
}
```

Now to check if at least one employee from the `currentEmployee` list is present in the `allEmployees` you can dump the contents of `allEmployees` into a `HashSet` and iterate over `currentEmployee` checking the elements against the set. Such check has an amortized cost of **O(1)**, therefore the overall time complexity would be **O(n)** (*n - represents the number of elements in the `currentEmployee` list).

```
public static boolean containsAny(List<EmployeeData> allEmployees,
                                  List<EmployeeData> currentEmployees) {
    
    Set<EmployeeData> allEmp = new HashSet<>(allEmployees);

    for (EmployeeData currentEmployee : currentEmployees) {
        if (allEmp.contains(currentEmployee)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

We can make this code very concise by using Stream API.

```
public static boolean containsAny(List<EmployeeData> allEmployees,
                                  List<EmployeeData> currentEmployees) {
    
    Set<EmployeeData> allEmp = new HashSet<>(allEmployees);
    
    return currentEmployees.stream().anyMatch(allEmp::contains);
}
```

**Note:** this code behaves in exactly the same way as the snippet you're provided, i.e. it would return after the first match.

It you want to find out whether **all elements** from the `currentEmployee` list are present in the `currentEmployee`, then you can make use of the method `Collection.containsAll()`:

```
public static boolean containsAll(List<EmployeeData> allEmployees,
                                  List<EmployeeData> currentEmployees) {
    
    Set<EmployeeData> allEmp = new HashSet<>(allEmployees);
    
    return allEmp.containsAll(currentEmployees);
}
```